# how can I use text file that has non-programming structure data in SwiftUI?

Tags: json, formatting, text-files, data-conversion

I am a two-month old coder learning SwiftUI.

I am trying to make a flash card app but I am not sure how to import data I have in the text file.

I assume I have to convert the text file into JSON format, but can you help me with how?

The text file has over 2,000 lines in this structure.

```
● あいそう[愛想] 　 [명사]→あいそ
● あいだがら[間柄] 　 [명사]사람과 사람의 사이;간, 혈족·친척간...
● あいま[合間] 　 [명사]틈;짬;참참
● あえて[敢えて] 　 [부사]감히;굳이, 구태여;그다지
● あおぐ[仰ぐ] 　 [동사]우러러보다, 치켜들다, 위를 보다
```

I want to parse them into 1) Japanese word, 2) Chinese character, 3) meaning in Korean

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

I tried to find the answer for a few hours in YouTube as well as paid lectures, but with no luck.